# Почему при оценке сложности алгоритмов используют O-большое, а не o-малое?

Tags: алгоритм, структуры-данных, сложность

Просьба, если в ответе решите использовать высшую математику, переведите сразу на обыденный язык, чтобы все было понятно и не возникло новых вопросов.

Comment: *Stack Overflow на русском — **это сайт вопросов и ответов** для профессиональных разработчиков программного обеспечения, энтузиастов программирования и системных администраторов. Сайт создан и управляется сообществом.* - вопрос в заголовке более чем уместен, @Harry

Comment: @Kromster В результате в вопросе нет вопроса. Тогда логично вообще убрать требование к телу вопроса, и разрешить задавать вопросы, состоящие только из заголовка.

Comment: Не уверен в корректности с математической точки зрения, но `o`-малое выглядит более строгим требованием, чем `O`-большое, что влечёт трудности с практическим применением. Когда говорят,  _имеет сложность `O(N^2)`_, то подразумевается, что сложность действительно может быть квадратичной. Когда говорят _имеет сложность `o(N^2)`_, то имеется ввиду, что сложность будет _гарантированно лучше_, чем квадратичная. Например для линейного поиска в массиве можно сказать, что он имеет сложность `O(N)`, но нельзя сказать `o(N)`. Можно сказать, что он имеет сложность `o(N * log(N))`, но это сбивает с толку.

Comment: Иными словами, `O`-большое сразу наглядно демонстрирует худший случай, а `o`-малое показывает некоторую недостижимую границу, и не совсем очевидно, что на самом деле представляет из себя худший случай.

Comment: Ну и `o`-малое тоже используется при оценки алгоритмов. Хороший пример — это коллекции `Map` и `Set` в javascript. Спецификация языка требует, чтобы время доступа к элементу коллекции _в среднем_ было [сублинейным](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Time_complexity#Sub-linear_time) ([24.1 Map Objects](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-map-objects)), т.е. в среднем имело сложность `o(n)`. В терминах `O`-большого это может быть сложность,например, `O(1)`, или `O(log(n))`, или даже `O(sqrt(n))`.

Comment: "Почему летает самолет? Просьба, если в ответе решите использовать физику, переведите сразу на обыденный язык, чтобы все было понятно и не возникло новых вопросов."

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*O*-большое - аналог нестрогого неравенства (≤),
*o*-малое - аналог строгого неравенства (<).

Пример:

```
s = 0
for i in range(0, n):
    for j in range(0, n):
        s += i * j
```

То, что его сложность **равна** *Cn<sup>2</sup>* очевидно - внешний цикл делает *n* повторений. Внутренний цикл - тоже *n* повторений. Тело внутреннего цикла считается за константу. По правилам комбинирования вложенных циклов перемножаем сложности - получаем *Cn<sup>2</sup>*. Но если его сложность **равна** квадрату, то она и **меньше либо равна** квадрату. Можем написать сложность алгоритма *O(n<sup>2</sup>)*.

В случае с *o*-малым нужно предъявить такую формулу, что сложность алгоритма будет **строго меньше** этой формулы. Например сложность этого алгоритма есть *o(n<sup>3</sup>)* - он работает быстрее чем любой кубический алгоритм. Или *o(n<sup>2.1</sup>)*, *o(n<sup>2+ε</sup>)* для любого ε > 0, или *o(n<sup>2</sup>log(n))*, или ещё бесконечное число вариантов из которых нельзя выбрать один "самый подходящий".

Аналогия на числах: есть формула *-x<sup>2</sup>*, оцените её максимальное значение.

Простой ответ в терминах *O*-большого — *-x<sup>2</sup> ≤ 0*. **Не превосходит**. А в терминах *o*-малого оценку привести сложнее: *-x<sup>2</sup> < 1*, *-x<sup>2</sup> < 0.1*, *-x<sup>2</sup> < ε* (*ε > 0*). Если вы предъявляете конкретный ответ со строгим неравенством, сразу можно сказать что ваш ответ не самый лучший - ε можно разделить пополам и получить лучший ответ.

Лучшего ответа нет вообще. Есть последовательность ответов, каждый лучше предыдущего. Поэтому строгое неравенство непрактично использовать при оценках сверху.

Comment: о-малое -- это не просто строго меньше, это строго меньше *для любого положительного множителя*

Comment: @PakUula, константа - деталь реализации. Есть определение *o*-малого через "верхний предел отношения равен нулю" - совсем без констант.

Answer (score 4):

**Совсем на пальцах**

о-малое - это не просто "меньше". Когда пишут, что сложность алгоритма - `о(f)`, то хотят сказать, что с ростом параметра алгоритма сложность растёт **гораааааааздо** медленнее, чем `f`. Там, на бесконечности, сложность алгоритма даже в микроскоп не разглядеть по сравнению с `f`. Ну или как песчинка по сравнению с галактикой. Очень-очень-очень намного-намного-меньше, короче.

О-большое - это не просто "меньше или равно". Это означает, что где-то там, на бесконечности, сложность алгоритма ведёт себя примерно как `f`.  Если совместить масштабы, то может быть даже совпадут. Ну или могут быть выбросы соответствующего размера. В случае о-малого как масштаб ни растягивай, всё равно мелко будет.

С практической точки зрения О-большое полезнее. Предположим, мы знаем, что два алгоритма имеют сложность о-малое от эн-в-кубе, `o(n^3)`. Что это нам даёт? Ничего. А если мы знаем, что у одного сложность `O(n^2)`, а у второго `O(n*log(n))`? Сразу ясно-понятно, что нужно брать второй.

*но как человек, которому в жизни довелось доказывать сложность алгоритма, я думаю, что причина использования О-больших в другом*

**Тоже на пальцах, но чуть сложнее**

Чисто из общих соображений: на ваш вопрос "*Почему при оценке сложности алгоритмов используют O-большое*?" ответить невозможно, так как он неверен.

При оценке сложности в специальной литературе, то есть не учебниках, используют и О-большое, и о-малое, и даже Омега-большую (Ω), омега-малую (ω) и Тета-большую (Θ). И даже используют знак ~ (тильда). Хуже того, для алгоритмов факторизации помимо О-Омега-Тета-тильда используют ещё и букву `L`.

Да что там специальная литература! В Википедии местами используют не только О-нотацию. Например, в статье о [рекуррентных соотношениях](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B0_%D0%BE_%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BA%D1%83%D1%80%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85_%D1%81%D0%BE%D0%BE%D1%82%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%88%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F%D1%85) (в английском эта теорема получила уважительное название [Master theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem_(analysis_of_algorithms))) текст пестрит Тета-нотацией.

И всё же, почему так широко используют О-большое? Чем О-большое удобнее о-малого? Давайте посмотрим на определение О-большого, для простоты взяв случай `n ⟶ ∞`:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Здесь `U` - окрестность бесконечности, то есть луч чисел `n > N` для некоторого `N`.

Что же написано в определении о-малого?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Видите в чём разница? В первом кванторе. Для О-большого стоит квантор существования, а для о-малого квантор всеобщности. Конечно же первый квантор доказывать гораздо проще: нашел константу `C`, доказал, что для всех достаточно  больших `n` неравенство выполняется, и свободен! С квантором всеобщности дело гораздо веселее. Нужно доказывать, что `|f(n)/g(n)| ⟶ 0`, то есть показать что там, на бесконечности, никаких выбросов быть не может. В большинстве случаев это шибко сложно, мало кто хочет с такой фигнёй связываться.

Возьмём для примера теорему о распределении простых чисел [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Чебышов сравнительно элементарными средствами доказал в 1850-м году, что `π(x)` "болтается вокруг" `x/ln(x)` и нашел константы, которые ограничивают отклонения. Но тот факт, что эти константы равны единице, и асимптотически `π(x)` сливается с `x/ln(x)` доказали только спустя 50 лет, причём это потребовало введения Риманом такой ниипической пушки, как дзета-функция, и аггрессивного развития теории функции комплексной переменной.

ИМХО, причина использования О-большого заключается именно в сложности доказательства теорем для о-малого.

Comment: Можете пожалуйста добавить абзац простыми словами, ну типа как для 5-классника, без всяких заумных "кванторов"? Мне кажется это сделает ответ гораздо понятнее для тех, кому эта тема не близка (и именно они задаются вопросом как топискстартер)

Comment: Кажется, сложность не доказательствах, а в отсутствии подходящих примеров. Например, алгоритм с константной сложностью. Как выразить его сложность в терминах о-малого? Мягко говоря, это очень сложно. Простой ответ - О-большое аналог нестрогого неравенства (<=), а о-малое аналог строгого (<). Ответ для нестрого неравенства формулируется значительно проще чем для строгого.

Comment: @Kromster кванторы заумны? Не понял :) Это же матанализ, первый семестр семестр первого курса. Я по простоте душевной думал, что люди, задающие вопрос "O vs o" должны были как минимум отучиться в вузе. Первый раз эти буковки возникают как раз в первом семестре, в теме про формулу Тейлора/Макларена.

Comment: На ютубе есть хороший канал с видео "объяснение какой-либо концепции на 5 уровнях" - ребенку, школьнику, первокурснику, аспиранту, доценту (примерно). Ну и темы разные, от бесконечности, до генной инженерии. К чему это я - почти все (и уж точно О) можно подать и в более простой форме, для затравки (как попросил автор вопроса). Впрочем право ваше, я лишь предложил улучшить ответ. Мне то вообще лень свой ответ писать ))

Comment: @PakUula, по поводу *абзаца простыми словами* и *`"... люди, задающие вопрос "O vs o" должны были как минимум отучиться в вузе ..."`*. Это сильное допущение. Людям, вообще, не зависимо от образования, свойственно любопытство (и лень). Вот, человек, не учившийся матану (или тот, что "знал, но забыл") читает где-то про O и o и хочет быстренько понять, а где тут собака порылась, спрашивает. Может, все же, имеет смысл дать ему понимание ситуации на доступном уровне.

Comment: @Kromster посмотрел, с какой скоростью растёт рейтинг вопроса, ужаснулся, и таки добавил *на пальцах* :)

Comment: Предположим, мы знаем, что два алгоритма имеют сложность O-большое от эн-в-кубе, `O(n^3)`. Что это нам даёт? Ничего. А если мы знаем, что у одного сложность `o(n^2)`, а у второго `o(n*log(n))`? Сразу ясно-понятно, что нужно брать второй. :)